# Dark mode and Google maps cookies

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 themes: white mode(default) and dark mode and when I reload the page/load another page it switches back to default theme and also it changes some images from html. How can I make a cookie to solve this problem?

```
var icon = document.getElementById("icon");

icon.onclick = function () {

document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
if(  document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")) {
    
    icon.src = "assets/white.svg";
    mis.src = "assets/misiune-b.svg"
    pnras.src = "assets/pnras-b.svg"
    bulb.src = "assets/white.svg"
    cam.src = "assets/cam-b.svg"
    man.src = "assets/man-b.svg"
    resurse.src = "assets/resurse-b.svg"
    consiliu.src = "assets/cladire-b.svg"
    dec.src = "assets/moneda-b.svg"
    pho.src = "assets/phone-b.svg"
    mail.src = "assets/mail-b.svg"
}
else {
    icon.src = "assets/moon.png"
    mis.src = "assets/misiune.svg"
    pnras.src = "assets/pnras.svg"
    bulb.src = "assets/.svg"
    cam.src = "assets/camera_.svg"
    man.src = "assets/management_.svg"
    resurse.src = "assets/resurse umane.svg"
    consiliu.src = "assets/ca.svg"
    dec.src = "assets/moneda.svg"
    pho.src = "assets/Phone.svg"
    mail.src = "assets/Mail.svg"
}

}
```

Also, another problem that I have is when I included a map from Google, I get this message:common.js:50          GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent?1shttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fembed&2sgoogle-maps-embed&7snq9kpa&10e1&11b0&callback=_xdc_._9jkh3h&client=google-maps-embed&token=75745 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: You save user's preference in localStorage, and when page loaded, read from localStorage and programmatically set the class name.

Comment: You could use your browser's [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), but that is limited to whatever browser you are using on a specific machine. If you have a server/webapp, then this type of information is typically saved as a user preference (eg, in a database).

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided would only work on the `HTML` you are currently on. By changing the page, realoding or closing, you reset all the variables and script stuff. The trick here is to use localstorage, to store the variables and access them even after change of page, reload or close.

The easiest answer is to point you to [this](https://medium.com/@haxzie/dark-and-light-theme-switcher-using-css-variables-and-pure-javascript-zocada-dd0059d72fa2) nice tutorial, where is everything explained

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the theme choice somewhere. You could save it to a cookie in JS, something like, when the icon is clicked, create a `selectedTheme` cookie...

`document.cookie = "selectedTheme=dark";`

Then in JS, you can say "if cookie === 'dark' add the dark mode class to body tag".

That or save the setting to a Database and do a similar if statement on the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Before your edit i wrote this, I hope this helps.
A lot of users don't accept cookies... So :

```js
        let darkMode = false;
        let myContent = null;
        let mySwitch = null;
        let display = null;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDomContentLoaded);
        function onDomContentLoaded(e){
            myContent = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            mySwitch = document.getElementById("switcher");
            display = document.getElementById("darkValue");
            display.textContent = "dark mode = " + darkMode;
            mySwitch.addEventListener("click",clickHandler);
        }
        function clickHandler(e){
            darkMode = !darkMode;
            
            if(darkMode==true){
                myContent.className = "black";
                display.textContent = "dark mode = " + darkMode;
            }
            else if(darkMode==false){
                myContent.className = "white";
                display.textContent = "dark mode = " + darkMode;
            }
        }
```

```css
        .white{
            background-color: beige;
            color: grey;
        }
        .black{
            background-color:darkslategrey;
            color: beige;
        }
```

```html
        <div id="myDiv" class="white">
            <p>My text</p>
            <p id="darkValue"></p>
            <button id="switcher">switcher</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css variables for managing colors and icons path